# Java Queues/Nodes what is this method doing?

Tags: java, list, methods, nodes

---My node class---

```
class Node<E> {
        public E data;
        public Node<E> next;

        Node(E data, Node<E> next)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
```

---My mystery method that is affecting my list---

```
public Node < E > mystery < E extends Comparable > (Node < E > first, E x) {
Node < E > p2 = null;
Node < E > p1 = first;
while (p1 != null && x.compareTo(p1.data) != 0) {
    p2 = p1;
    p1 = p1.next;
}
if (p1 != null) {
    if (p1 == first) {
        first = first.next;
    } else {
        p2.next = p1.next;
    }
}
return first;
}
```

I've tried converting my "mystery" method into "psuedocode" to try and understand it better. But I am still not understanding what it is doing.

--My psuedocode--

```
-----While loop------
While p1 is not null/empty, and while x is not equal to p1
Set p2 equal to p1
and set p1 equal to p1.next

----If Statements------
if p1 is not empty/null and if p1 is equal to the first item in the list 
   then set first to first.next (moving the pointer)

if none of the above is able to be ran
   then set p2.next equal to p1.next

and return first.
```

My list looks like this...
ptr [ ] --> [10][ ] --> [20][ ] --> [30][ ] --> [40][ ] --> [50][Ø]

I need to understand what my mystery method is doing exactly, and be able to see what would happen to the list if something like this was called: ptr = mystery( ptr, 50 );

Any help would be great. I have been stuck on this for some time now... Thank you.

Comment: "what would happen to the list if something like this was called: ptr = mystery( ptr, 50 );" can't you run it and figure out (using a debugger if you need to)

Comment: A place to start would be asking yourself What does the while loop do? Sure you changed the code to "psuedocode", but what is the purpose of that loop? Specifically, what is the value of `p1` and `p2` when the loop completes?

Comment: I think thats his fundamental issue @clcto, he isn't sure and didn't write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     Node < E > p2 = null;
>     Node < E > p1 = first;
>     while (p1 != null && x.compareTo(p1.data) != 0) {
>         p2 = p1;
>         p1 = p1.next;
>     }
> ```

This means: walk the elements in the linked list until either:

- You find an element equal to `x`

  - In this case `p1` contains the element, and `p2` is the node before `p1`
- You reach the end (did not find element equal to `x`)

  - In this case `p1` is `null`

> ```
> if (p1 != null) {
>     if (p1 == first) {
>         first = first.next;
>     } else {
>         p2.next = p1.next;
>     }
> }
> return first;
> ```

What will happen:

- If `p1` is `null`, that means the element `x` is not in the linked list. The `if` fails, and the method returns `first` unchanged
- If `p1` is not `null`, that means the element `x` was found, contained in `p1`

  - If `p1` is the `first` node, then return the second node
  - Otherwise make `p2.next` point to `p1.next`, and return the first node

In short: the method searches for a node containing `x`, if it finds it, it deletes it.
The method returns the first node, or if it was deleted then the second node.

Comment: Awesome reply. I get it now. Thank you so much for your help! I should be able to continue on now, and figure it all out.